# Html Helper "Select2": Submit normal form

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-select2

i'm about to submit normal html (MVC-Razor) form. though I'm new to MVC and i don't wanna use unnecessary Ajax because it take time for me to learn, and I'm in hurry and also with my complex model which contain other models i'm wonder how should i take back data...

in this form, i'm using Select2, which is feeded from a normal select tag...
what i want is to submit my form on any change to this control, and send its value back to server.

the issue is in some of my test, it has name but no value, and in some it even doesn't appear to have a container name.

here is my page code:

```
@model SinglePage.Models.SinglePageIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<h2>خانه</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(c=>Model.Customer.Code)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#selectCustomer").select2({
                placeholder: "انتخاب مشتری",
                allowclear: true
            }).select2('val', @((Model != null && Model.Customer != null)? Model.Customer.Code:0))
                .on("select2-selecting", function (e) {
                var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
                form.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>


    <fieldset>
        <select id="selectCustomer" name="selectCustomer">
            <option></option>
            @foreach (var customer in Model.CustomerList)
            {
                <option value="@customer.Code">@Html.DisplayFor(c => customer.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(c=>customer.LastName)</option>
            }
        </select>

    </fieldset>
}
```

and here is my post request which does not contain "selectCustomer" and value for it.

[image: Request Incomplete (setlect2)]

### -Extra Help (help is recommended but not required)

Also if you have any suggestion for me to read my data, or name my item, that i can read them back through model, i'll be happy to take advice, for now i'm going to use "Request.Form[]".

but my model structure is like this:

```
namespace SinglePage.Models
{
    public class SinglePageIndexViewModel
    {
        public List<Models.Customer> CustomerList { set; get; }
        public List<Models.Item> ItemList { set; get; }
        public Models.Customer Customer { set; get; }
        public Models.Factor Factor { set; get; }
        public List<Models.FactorItem> FactorItemList { set; get; }
    }
}

namespace SinglePage.Models
{
    public class SinglePageIndexViewModel
    {
        public List<Models.Customer> CustomerList { set; get; }
        public List<Models.Item> ItemList { set; get; }
        public Models.Customer Customer { set; get; }
        public Models.Factor Factor { set; get; }
        public List<Models.FactorItem> FactorItemList { set; get; }
    }
}

namespace SinglePage.Models
{
    public class FactorItem
    {
        public int Code { set; get; }
        public int FactorCode { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public int Count { set; get; }
        public decimal ItemPrice { set; get; }

        public decimal TotalPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return ItemPrice*Count;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace SinglePage.Models
{
    public class Factor
    {
        public int Code { set; get; }
        public int CustomerCode { set; get; }
        public DateTime Date { set; get; }
        public decimal PaidPrice { set; get; }
    }
}

namespace SinglePage.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Code { set; get; }
        public string FirstName { set; get; }
        public string LastName { set; get; }
        public string IdentityNo { set; get; }
        public string Telephone { set; get; }
        public string Address { set; get; }
    }
}
```

And i pass data using first model which contains all model.

Thank you all,
Hassan F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are submitting the form before selecting the value. submit it after selecting value. try submitting the form on `change`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#selectCustomer").select2({
                placeholder: "انتخاب مشتری",
                allowclear: true
            }).select2('val', @((Model != null && Model.Customer != null)? Model.Customer.Code:0))
                .on("change", function (e) {
                var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
                form.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: there were a page I'm wonder in which website, contain lot of events include change, and select2_selecting, when i worked with drop down, the selecting logged the changes, but change didn't so i didn't though it work at all.

thank you

i'll test for now.

Comment: worked... thank you again, but you think it's good the way i take information from post? or i should do something else to take this parameter from post